# How to deploy a streamlit app to Heroku within a Docker container?

Tags: python, docker, heroku, streamlit

I recently started using `streamlit`, which is definitely an awesome library for Dashboarding and visualizing Machine Learning applications.

However, my deployment workflow is currently Docker and Heroku. I can't find simple documentation on how to easily deploy a `streamlit` app hosted within a Docker container onto Heroku. Therefore, I wanted to document something simple I found here.

Answer (score 2):

After a little bit of research and play around with the code, this is the simplest way that seems to be working:

1. create `.streamlit` folder where a `config.toml` will live
2. Within the `config.toml` write the following code:

```
[browser]
serverAddress = '0.0.0.0'
```

3. Build your Dockerfile with whatever you want in simply at the end, add this command:

```
CMD streamlit run --server.port $PORT app.py
```

For example, here is my complete Dockerfile based on the [code example](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/get-started/create-an-app) that streamlit currently provides

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3

WORKDIR /home/app

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install nano unzip
RUN apt install curl -y

RUN curl -fsSL https://get.deta.dev/cli.sh | sh
RUN pip install boto3 pandas gunicorn streamlit
COPY . /home/app

CMD streamlit run --server.port $PORT app.py
```

In development, simply run your container with a `PORT` environment variable and a port mapping like this:

`docker run -it MY_DOCKER_IMAGE -p HOST_PORT:CONTAINER_PORT -e PORT=CONTAINER_PORT`

If everything works correctly locally, then you can follow this tutorial to deploy your container to Heroku :

- [Deploy to heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime#getting-started)